# Jquery returning the wrong selected index of a radio button group

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and have a radio button group. When the user clicks the radio button, I need to grab the index of the button he/she selected. My [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3028/) returns the wrong value. Instead of the newly-selected index, it gets the previously-selected index. How do I correct it?

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <a class="btn btn-link">Index 0</a>
    <a class="btn btn-link active">Index 1</a>
    <a class="btn btn-link">Index 2</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var selected;

$('.btn-group > .btn, .btn[data-toggle="button"]').click(function() {
    selected = $(".btn-group").find(".active").index();
    alert(selected);
});
```

Comment: `selected = $(this).index();`

Comment: Your active class selector searches is not necessarily correct because you're not clicking to the class "active". You should use (this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var selected;

$('.btn-group > .btn, .btn[data-toggle="button"]').click(function() {
    selected = $(this).index();
    alert(selected);
});
```